# Heroku behaving differently to development machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, heroku, spree

I have the following code in my controller:

```
class PagesController < Spree::BaseController
  before_filter { render_404 if params[:id] =~ /(\.|\\)/ }

  caches_action :show, :if => Proc.new { Spree::Config[:cache_static_content] }, :layout => false

  respond_to :html

  # GET /pages/about-us
  def show
    @page = Page.published.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
    if @page.blank?
      render_404
    else
      respond_to do |format|
      #check if this is only a partial update
        unless @page.is_subpage?
            format.html # show.html.erb#
        else
            format.html {render :layout => false, :text => @page.body}
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Basically, if the page is a sub_page, I dont need to layout, just the html contained in @page.body (an ajax request).

This works fine in development, but on heroku it seems to ignore the `render :layout => false`

I checked on the heroku console that @page.is_subpage? is working as expected which it does, which rules out any problems to do with the unless.

Is there another way of doing the :layout => false?

What I actually end up with on heroku, is a full page withing a div (including whatever is in the layouts/application.html.erb

EDIT:

The gem I'm using can be found [here](https://github.com/abepetrillo/spree_pages)

Comment: Have you tested the production environment on your own machine?

Comment: The cause was cacheing is turned on in production, so +1 for telling me to go look at production settings instead of blaming heroku :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Found the culprit:

```
 caches_action :show, :if => Proc.new { Spree::Config[:cache_static_content] }, :layout => false
```

This is turned off in development and test mode, but that was somehow over-riding the behaviour of the controller. I've commented this out until I have time to fix this properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because you have not commit the code into heroku or heroku is caching your old version of code.

Try to change something in the controller file, then commit it, then push to heroku. It should work

Comment: I don't think its this, I did as you said just to make sure and I still get the same behaviour. The controller is actually part of a gem, did bundle update, generated a new Gemfile.lock and still doesn't work